# How did Leo Valdez die?

Tags: rick-riordan, the-heroes-of-olympus

Towards the end of The Blood of Olympus Leo Valdez, Jason Grace, and Piper Mclean with he help of Festus trap Gaia in the sky. Jason and Piper then drop back to the ground while Leo uses his powers to explode Gaia. As Leo is immune to flames, heat and most explosions why does using his own power against Gaia kill him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leo's death appears to be attributable to the power of the explosive used to attack Gaia, along with the presence of [Imperial Gold](http://riordan.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Gold), used as shrapnel

> The throwing arm was already primed with a full payload of Imperial
>   gold and explosives. The augur rushed about, tripping over gears and
>   anchor spikes, fumbling with the ropes. Every so often he glanced up
>   at Festus the dragon.

and

> ‘No. It is not your fault.’ But Nico wasn’t quite so ready to forgive
>   himself. He’d spent the last forty-eight hours replaying the scene
>   with Octavian at the catapult, wondering if he’d done wrong thing.
>   **Perhaps the explosive power of that projectile had helped destroy
>   Gaia. Or perhaps it had unnecessarily cost Leo Valdez his life.**

This is backed up by his appearance when we next see him

> LEO WAS DEAD.
>
> He knew that with absolute certainty. He just didn’t understand why it
>   hurt so much. He felt like every cell in his body had exploded. **Now
>   his consciousness was trapped inside a charred crispy husk of demigod
>   roadkill.** The nausea was worse than any carsickness he’d ever had. He
>   couldn’t move. He couldn’t see or hear. He could only feel pain.

Comment: Disclaimer, I know nothing about this book series, I merely happen to have a copy beside me. Feel free to use these quotes to make a better answer if this looks funky.

Comment: "happen to have a copy beside me" ... right.

Comment: @randal'thor - It fell off the back of a lorry, guv'nor.

Comment: @Valorum you might want to change this now. Leo is back. As fresh as new born, and he gets his happily ever after with Calypso with two other Lesbian ex-huntresses.

Comment: @Trusha_Patel - It sounds like you need to post a new answer

Comment: Nah, I am fine here. Rick wouldn’t be happy with blatant spoilers!